# R: Subtract a row from others in group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame (or data.table) like below

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
1      A     23
1      B     26
2      A     20
2      C     10
```

I have this data grouped on `Col1`. I want to get number of rows which are within certain range (say 5; difference calculated on Col3) from each row.

So I should get a result like this

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
1      A     23  1  
1      B     26  1
2      A     20  0
2      C     10  0
```

In this case, the base is Col3 of each row. So for example - row1,Col3 has one row in the group which is within 5 distance from row1, Col3. Similarly in the second group there are no rows which are within 5 distance from any of them.

How can I do it in data.table?

Comment: Within a range based on what? What values are we comparing, and what value is the base value?

Comment: row 2 and 3 are not within range of 5, so i would expect the value of row3 and col4 to be zero not 1?

Comment: @BigDataScientist OP said grouped by Col1 so I think that's okay, but I don't understand why in row 1 Col4 is 2 but in row 2 Col4 is 1, if I understand OP correctly they should both be 2

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize that mistake when posting. I just corrected it.

Comment: Can you please remove the downvote. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ave(abs(ave(df$Col3,
            df$Col1,
            FUN = function(x) c(Inf, (x[1] - x)[-1]))) <= 5,
    df$Col1,
    FUN = sum)
#[1] 1 1 0 0
```

The inner `ave` calculates the difference between the elements within same group. The outer `ave` calculates the number of rows with absolute difference less than 5.

**UPDATE**

```
#DATA
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1,1,2,2,2), Col3 = c(24,25,21,20,10))

temp = ave(abs(ave(df$Col3,
            df$Col1,
            FUN = function(x) c(Inf, (x[1] - x)[-1]))) <= 5,
    df$Col1,
    FUN = sum)
replace(temp, abs(ave(df$Col3, df$Col1, FUN = function(x) c(0, (x[1] - x)[-1]))) > 5, 0)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Since diff only calculates consecutive differences.

Comment: Looks right to me, I like the `(x[1] - x)[-1]` method for finding the difference of every value.

Comment: `df <- data.table(Col1 = c(1,1,2,2,1,3,3), Col3 = c(24,25,26,28,16,18,20));df <- group_by(df, Col1); df$Col4 <- ave(abs(ave(df$Col3,df$Col1,FUN = function(x) c(Inf, (x[1] - x)[-1]))) <= 5,df$Col1,FUN = sum)`. this results in all 1's. But for `df$Col1 = 16` it should result in 0

Comment: I don't understand why people have downvoted my question. The solution you have given only works for the given example. If I add one more row like this 'df <- data.table(Col1 = c(1,1,2,2,2), Col3 = c(24,25,21,20,10))' . Your solution does not work.

Comment: Thank you @d.b. Take this example `df <- data.table(Col1 = c(1,1,2,2,2), Col3 = c(24,25,21,20,10))'. The output for this should be `data.table(Col1 = c(1,1,2,2,2), Col3 = c(24,25,21,20,10), Col4 = c(1,1,1,1,0))`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Using the data.table and sapply.

```
df <- data.table(Col1 = c(1,1,2,2,2), Col3 = c(24,25,21,20,10))
df[,Col4 := sapply(Col3, function (y) (sum(abs(y - Col3)<=5)-1)), by = .(Col1)]
```